# How do I get a value from a class name using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get a value from a class name but the onlything a could get thill now is a [ ] output.
so, what I'm supposed to do in the following code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/cambio/')
time.sleep(5)
dolar = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('currency2')
time.sleep(5)
print(dolar)
```

Comment: Do you mean get the text of an element with a `currency2`  classname? Which value are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `selenium` to get that information, try:

```
import requests

u = "https://api.cotacoes.uol.com/currency/intraday/list/?format=JSON&fields=bidvalue,askvalue,maxbid,minbid,variationbid,variationpercentbid,openbidvalue,date&currency=1"
j = requests.get(u).json()
dolar = j['docs'][0]['bidvalue']
# 5.5916
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/567f8bb0a7)

---

Notes:

- If you need other info, like daily variation (`variationpercentbid`) search on json the object:

[image]

- Change the currency value at the end of the url for a different currency, for example, `currency=5`, will give you the `EUR` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **get_attribute** to retrieve value of web element, Also in your code you there is no element with class name currency2.

**Please find below example :**

```
<input class="field normal" name="currency2" value="5,59" data-audience-click="{&quot;reference&quot;:&quot;ativar-campo-texto&quot;,&quot;component&quot;:&quot;currency-converter&quot;}" xpath="1">
```

**Code to retrieve value:**

```
driver.get('https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/cambio/')
currency = driver.find_element_by_name('currency2')
print currency.get_attribute("value")
```

**Output::**

5,59